# MySQL SELECT add days interval to datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime, dateadd

I have a column in my database called SHARE_DATE.  I'd like to be able to select all records where SHARE_DATE + 7 DAYS is greater than today.

I've tried the query below but am not getting any of the records that I should.  I feel like I'm close but can't quite figure it out.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_shares WHERE DATE_ADD(DATE_SHARE, INTERVAL +7 DAY) > NOW();
```

Comment: Hard to say, What is `SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_shares`? What results are you getting? Performance wise you are better writing `SELECT * FROM TABLE_shares WHERE DATE_SHARE > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` which can use a `DATE_SHARE` index.

Comment: @danblack Thank you!  I tried your query and it's working.  Not sure what I was doing but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments resolved with:

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE_shares
WHERE DATE_SHARE > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Which can use a DATE_SHARE index

Answer (score 0):

use this statment.
reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_shares WHERE DATE_SHARE > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```